# How can i move my h1 headings on top of my flexbox containers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created 3 flexbox containers (container for controlling the other two flexbox containers. In my primary and secondary flex containers i inserted 4 images and a h1 which are all wrapped together, but how can i move my h1's on top of the flex containers(outside of the flex containers) ?
I started experimenting with flexbox today so consider my a rookie.

JsFiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/2fw7w8qn/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/2fw7w8qn/) or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework.css">
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Electrolize' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="UTF-8">      
  <title>NK Electrical LTD</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div class="container">
     <div class="primary">
         <h1>Menu</h1>
  <li class="flex-item1"><img src="img/electrical.png"></li>
  <li class="flex-item1"><img src="img/emergency.png"></li>
  <li class="flex-item1"><img src="img/homeappliances1.png"></li>
  <li class="flex-item1"><img src="img/homeappliances2.png"></li>

    </div>
             <div class="secondary">
         <h1>Our latest products</h1>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="img/1.jpg"></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="img/2.jpg"></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="img/3.jpg"></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="img/4.jpg"></li>
    </div>
         </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Framework.css

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{font-family: 'Electrolize', sans-serif;}
ul{list-style: none;padding: 0;margin: 0;}
.container{display: flex;flex-direction: column;}
.primary{display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center;background-color:#1c1c1c;margin:0% 25%;padding:1%;}
.secondary{display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;;justify-content: center;background-color:#1c1c1c;margin:0% 25%;padding:1%;}
.flex-item {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-item1{
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

h1{flex:1;color:white;font-size:1.5em;font-weight: 300;border-bottom: 3px solid white;margin-bottom: 5%;padding:2%;margin-top:0;}
img{width:100px; height:auto;}
div{list-style: none;}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid...an `h1` cannot be a child of a `ul`...fix that first.

Comment: It would also help if we knew what this was supposed to look like.

Comment: [Result image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vdic5z&s=9#.VuR84JN96i5)

Comment: You can't just edit out the `ul`...it's now invalid HTML because `li` must be children and the only children of a `ul`.

Comment: Besides the H1 issue, I don't think your layout results in what the image portrays. If you stretch the Fiddle to accommodate  enough space for the boxes to be side by side, it'll turn into a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really clear on the exact nature of what it is you are attempting here but it looks like you should be using rows for each of the menus and headings.

Now there may be additional layout for the container but without a really clear idea of the requirement it's hard to be sure.

For the basic layout of each ROW you don't need flexbox initially.

The *valid* structure would be something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <h1>Menu Heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now the row will be 100% wide by default (unless in a flex-column but that's another question).

The `h1` and `ul` are block level and so will also be 100% wide *but* the `li` need to be horizontal too. **This** is where we can use flexbox.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex-item {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
.row {
  background: #c0ffee;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1>Menu Heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <h1>Second Heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h1>Menu Heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
    <li class="flex-item"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you it works, but how can i stop the ul & h1 from taking full width? display:inline-block? or is there any way with flexbox features ?i apprieciate your help

Comment: But you want them full width don't you? As I said, it's not clear what you are trying to do. If you wrap them in a container they will be as wide as the container...then you can limit the width of the container.

Comment: nvm, i found a solution. I renamed "row" class to 2 different classes and i gave them 50% width and margin: 0 auto for centering. Same also with h1